# PHP: echoing variables and displaying output through selectbox

Tags: php, mysql

I am having difficulties grasping the concept of echoing a variable from a database through php. Instead getting a variable in string format i get an integer. How can i display the category string variable through the select box?

here is the info in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
   `c_id` tinyint(4) not null auto_increment,
   `category` varchar(30) not null,
   PRIMARY KEY (`c_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5;

INSERT INTO `category` (`c_id`, `category`) VALUES ('1', 'Animals >');
INSERT INTO `category` (`c_id`, `category`) VALUES ('2', 'Humans >');
INSERT INTO `category` (`c_id`, `category`) VALUES ('3', 'Technology >');
INSERT INTO `category` (`c_id`, `category`) VALUES ('4', 'Oceans >');
INSERT INTO `category` (`c_id`, `category`) VALUES ('5', 'Desert >');
INSERT INTO `category` (`c_id`, `category`) VALUES ('6', 'Jungles >');
```

Here is my php:

```
<select name="category" size="6" onChange="autoSubmit();">
        <?php

        //POPULATE DROP DOWN MENU WITH CATEGORIES
        $conn = new PDO($DSN, $USERNAME, $PASSWORD);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY c_id";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($categories))
        {        
            echo ("<option value=\"$row[c_id]\" " . ($category == $row["c_id"] ? " selected" : "") . ">$row[category]</option>");        
        }

        ?>


    <option value="1" <?php if($category == 1) echo " selected"; ?>><? echo $category; ?></option>
    <option value="2" <?php if($category == 2) echo " selected"; ?>><? echo $category; ?></option>
    <option value="3" <?php if($category == 3) echo " selected"; ?>><? echo $category; ?></option>
    <option value="4" <?php if($category == 4) echo " selected"; ?>><? echo $category; ?></option>
    <option value="5" <?php if($category == 5) echo " selected"; ?>><? echo $category; ?></option>
    <option value="6" <?php if($category == 6) echo " selected"; ?>><? echo $category; ?></option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Where is the code that assigns the $category variable?

Comment: Ahhhh!  Loops are your friend!  Also, `>` is an html special character, so you need to be escaping your `echo $category;` like `echo htmlspecialchars($category);`.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either the improved [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) extension or the [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) abstraction layer.

Comment: The `<select></select>` tags should be on either side of your PHP codeblock; you should remove the `WHERE` clause from your SQL; and you do not need to manually include the `<option>..</option>` code because that is all constructed/output by the PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Upgrading to an answer*)

1. The `<select></select>` tags should be on either side of your PHP codeblock;
2. You should remove the `WHERE` clause from your SQL; and
3. You do not need to manually include the `<option>..</option>` code because that is all constructed/output by the PHP.

For example, using PDO:

```
<select name="category" size="6" onChange="autoSubmit();">
<?php
  $dbh = new PDO($DSN, $USERNAME, $PASSWORD);
  $qry = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY c_id');

  while ($row = $qry->fetch()) {
    echo '<option value="' . $row['c_id'] . '"';
    if ($row['c_id'] == $category) echo ' selected';
    echo '>' . htmlentities($row['category']) . '</option>'
  }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you for your advice and response. Pardon my ignorance i am new to this.

Answer (score 2):

this may help you and remember the third point mentioned by eggyal

> 3)You do not need to manually include the .. code
>   because that is all constructed/output by the PHP.

```
<select name="category" size="6" onChange="autoSubmit();">
        <?php

        //POPULATE DROP DOWN MENU WITH CATEGORIES
        $dbh = new PDO($DSN, $USERNAME, $PASSWORD);
        $qry = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY c_id');

        while ($row = $qry->fetch()) {
        {        
            if($row[c_id] == $category)
                $selected = "selected=\"selected\"";            
            echo ("<option value=\"{$row['c_id']}\" {$selected}>{$row['category']}</option>");        
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see one issue - not sure if this is your question? This is how you do the "selected" bit.

```
<option value="1" <?php if($category == 1) echo ' "selected=selected"'; ?>><? echo $category; ?></option>
```

But we need to see your code, where you assign the $category variables to know more

Comment: Only required in XHTML; in HTML, `selected` without `=selected` is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the formula with your example set of data:

1. [Connect database](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) and prepare the query (using [PDO extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)):

   ```
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_database', $user, $pass);
    $query = 'SELECT `c_id`, `category` FROM `category`';
   ```
2. [Execute query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) and push it to a [PHP array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

   ```
    foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row) {
        $categories[$row['c_id']] = $row['category'];
    }
   ```
3. [Loop through the array](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and output HTML:

   ```
    <?php $my_selected_category = 3; ?>
    <select name="category" size="6" onChange="autoSubmit();">
        <?php foreach($categories as $id => $name) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>" <?php echo $id == $my_selected_category ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>><?php echo $name; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
   ```

   Note that I've used the [ternary operator](https://www.php.net/ternary#language.operators.comparison.ternary) instead of a [`if-else`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) control structure to conditionally echo `selected="selected"`. The operator may ease your life in some situations.

Comment: Why loop over database results populating an array (could be very memory-expensive with a large resultset), only then to loop over that array?  Why not output directly from looping over the results?

Comment: @eggyal Good point. There are some reasons that come to my mind: 1. There are many ways, this is one of them; 2. Reusability; 3. The example dataset is small; 4. It's good to learn to separate different layers of the application.